# jQuery taking over all anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup, anchor

I have implemented jQuery and jQuery mobile for popups, but after some testing I noticed that jQuery is taking over all anchors. If I comment out the link to the jQuery scripts either one and my anchors work as expected to, if I uncomment them those anchors are taken over again and won't allow the href to go through properly. Anyone know how to resolve this, quite irritating to say the least. Here is sample...

```
<div>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.somesite.com">Somesite</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
<div>
 <a href="#popupVideo" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-inline="true">Click</a>
 <div data-role="popup" id="popupVideo" data-overlay-theme="a" data-theme="d" data-tolerance="15,15" class="ui-content">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.somevideo.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
</div>

    $( document ).on( "pageinit", function() {
        winW = window.innerWidth;
        winH = window.innerHeight;

        $( "#popupVideo iframe" )
            .attr( "width", 0 )
            .attr( "height", 0 );

        $( "#popupVideo" ).on({
            popupbeforeposition: function() {
                var size = scale( winW, winH, 15, 1 ),
                    w = size.width,
                    h = size.height;

                $( "#popupVideo iframe" )
                    .attr( "width", w )
                    .attr( "height", h );
            },
            popupafterclose: function() {
                $( "#popupVideo iframe" )
                    .attr( "width", 0 )
                    .attr( "height", 0 );    
            }
        });
    });
```

Then I have the proper code that comes with the example from jQuery, nothing in that code is anchor specific and is id specific. Plus if I delete that script that adjust the popup it still doesn't work and the only thing I have linked is the jQuery files. I am using the most recent jQuery as well if that helps 1.9.1 and mobile 1.3.0 I was using 1.2.0 but thought maybe the newer would fix the issue but to no avail. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us your javascript code.

Comment: Seriously, why **wouldn't** you think your Javascript code is important to include? Especially with this question

Comment: I added the JS even if I delete that code the links still don't work and the popup is still trying to happen. This just sizes the popup window...

Comment: This isn't something that happens when you just include jQuery js scripts. So we need to see what you added

Comment: You have my code... the anchor link and the popup video I just took out the href links as they are not open to public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are referring to the default behavior of jQuery mobile.  The default behavior of an anchor tag in jQuery mobile is to use an ajax request:

> jQuery Mobile is designed to work with simple page linking conventions.
>   Essentially, you can link pages and assets as you normally would, and
>   jQuery Mobile will automatically handle page requests in a single-page
>   model, using Ajax when possible. When Ajax isn't possible (such as a
>   non-same-domain url, or if specified using certain attributes on the
>   link), a normal http request is used instead.
>
> The goal of this model is to allow developers to create websites using
>   best practices — where ordinary links will "just work" without any
>   special configuration — while creating a rich, native-like experience
>   that can't be achieved with standard HTTP requests.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

Furthermore:

> Links that point to other domains or that have rel="external",
>   data-ajax="false" or target attributes will not be loaded with Ajax.
>   Instead, these links will cause a full page refresh with no animated
>   transition. Both attributes (rel="external" and data-ajax="false")
>   have the same effect, but a different semantic meaning: rel="external"
>   should be used when linking to another site or domain, while
>   data-ajax="false" is useful for simply opting a page within your
>   domain from being loaded via Ajax. Because of security restrictions,
>   the framework always opts links to external domains out of the Ajax
>   behavior.
>
> In version 1.1, we've added support for using data-ajax="false" on a
>   parent container which allows you to exclude a large number of links
>   from the Ajax navigation system. This avoids the need to add this
>   attribute to every link in a container. To activate this
>   functionality, $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled must be set to true.
>   Please check Configuring Defaults before using and setting this
>   option.
>
> Note: When building a jQuery Mobile application where the Ajax
>   navigation system is disabled globally or frequently disabled on
>   individual links, we recommend disabling the $.mobile.pushStateEnabled
>   global configuration option to avoid inconsistent navigation behavior
>   in some browsers.

Comment: I see thanks for the quick and direct response. I guess I will have to figure out a better solution for this page. Thanks again.

Comment: You can always exclude a parent object to deal with a large number of links.